# Qt Creator gdb show C array elements

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gdb, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator all the time to write C, C++, Qt programs.
Recently I came across an issue while debugging C++ code.

Generally Qt Creator's debugging view allows to see the contents of std::vector, but it doesn't allow for C style arrays.

Here's what it looks like

[image]

In the image `same` is a vector of bool, I can see the contents inside it, whereas `notSame` is a C style array of bool (i.e. `bool notSame[n];`), which doesn't allow to peek inside it.

Any suggestions to make C style arrays allow peeking inside them ?

Note: I'm using Qt Creator 2.8.1 & gdb 7.6 on a Linux machine.

Thank you.

Cheers :)

Comment: Did you get values now?

Comment: yes, but isn't there a way that makes Qt Creator do this by itself ?

Comment: unfortunately no.. there isn't any ready-made way in GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In expression evaluator try below

> *notSame@10

infact you can write `n` as below

```
*notSame@n
```